# How to get a sorted result from DynamoDB at runtime

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table with a lot of fields. Is there a way to make a query on it and receive the results sorted according to a certain field that is chosen at runtime by the user using AWS SDK for java?

I know that `.withScanIndexForward()` allows to define if it is in ascending or descending order, but I would like to tell which column to sort each time the query is requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, DynamoDB does not support a general purpose "ORDER BY columnname" feature.

DynamoDB tables are key/value, where key values must be unique. The key can be a single partition key or a composite of a partition key and a sort key. You can also create secondary indexes.

If you want DynamoDB to support queries sorted on a particular attribute (column) then you need to create a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) (GSI) that supports it. Then you can query the GSI.

Without a supporting GSI, you would have to sort the query results client-side.

Comment: That's all that I wanted to know. Thanks!